# Save section of webpage as HTML

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to save a portion of a webpage and save it as html file.

I can do it manually like this:

When I use F12 (developer tools) in Chrome or Mozilla and use the selector to select the position of the website I want, I see a `div` and I copy the Xpath. Then I copy the HTML of that element and paste into a notepad editor and save it as HTML.

I've used before Selenium IDE but I don't find a way to save the content of the Xpath of that div.

Is there a way to do it with a combination of Selenium IDE and JavaScript or Python?

Maybe someone could suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: pip install selenium, in python.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. May you show some example how would be with Selenium Python?

Answer (score -1):

this is just selenium example, not your particular answer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random


from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys




seed = 1
random.seed(seed)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop-header-cnt']/div[2]/div[3]/input")

# Put the word "history" in the search box and hit enter
element.send_keys("pantaloons")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)
for i in range(1000):
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(120):
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(0.10)

    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //*[@id='desktopSearchResults']/div[2]/section/div[2]/ul/li[12]/a")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(1)




#
#
# # Get a list of elements (videos) that get returned by the search
# search_results = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
#
# # Click randomly on one of the first five results
# search_results[random.randint(0,10)].click()
#
# # Go to the end of the page (I don't know if this is necessary
#
# #
# time.sleep(4)
#
# # Get the recommended videos the same way as above. This is where the problem starts, because recommended_videos essentially becomes the same thing as the previous page's search_results, even though the browser is in a new page now.
# while True:
#     recommended_videos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='dismissable']/div/a")
#     print(recommended_videos)
#     recommended_videos[random.randint(1,4)].click()
#     time.sleep(4)
```

You can try to dump page source and parse it, or dump only element source.

Page source to pageSource variable (Java):

String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
Element source to elementSource variable (Java):

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
String elementSource = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see in your example how to take a portion of the webpage given by an Xpath, ID and save it to an html file.